# Difficult to store Shared preferences value to SQLIte in Android and having null value stored

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I think i ran out from ideas about how to do this. I am building and TODO app with  register and login feature. Once a user is logged, can create new todos task in SQLite(for now), later i want to delete and rename  todos as well.

This is my DB class with SQliteHelper.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

// User table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

 // User Table Columns names
private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

 //Table mToDo task name
private final static String mTODO = "Todos"; 

//Todos table columns names
private final static String TASK_ID = "task_Id"; //autoincrement
private final static String user_Id =  "userId";
private final static String TITLE = "title";
private final static String CONTENT = "content";

 // create table sql query
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
        + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + 
 ")";

private String CREATE_mTODO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + mTODO + "("
        + TASK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + user_Id + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + TITLE + " TEXT," + CONTENT + " TEXT" + ")";

// drop table sql query
private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 //        this.ctx = context;
}

 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_mTODO_TABLE);

}

 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //Drop User Table if exist
    db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);


    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}
```

> Adding new Task to second table

```
 public void add(ToDo todoTask) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 //        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
 //                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
 //        String d = sp.toString();

 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TITLE, todoTask.getTitle());
    values.put(CONTENT, todoTask.getContent());

 //        values.put(user_Id,todoTask.getUserID(d));


// Inserting Row
    db.insert(mTODO, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

> ToDo.java

```
public class ToDo {

private int id;
private String userID;
private String title;
private String content;

public ToDo(String content, int id, String title, String userID) {
    this.content = content;
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.userID = userID;
}

public ToDo(String content, String title, String userID) {
    this.content = content;
    this.title = title;
    this.userID = userID;
}

public ToDo() {
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public int getId(String name) {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getUserID(String userID) {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}
}
```

> Add activity class  with inputs and add method

```
public class addTask extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText titleUser;
private EditText contentDesc;
private DatabaseHelper db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_task);
    Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addToDo);
    titleUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleID);
    contentDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contentDescId);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                AddItem();
        }


    });

}



private void AddItem() {
    ToDo todo = new ToDo();
    todo.setTitle(titleUser.getText().toString().trim());
    todo.setContent(contentDesc.getText().toString().trim());
    db.add(todo);
    finish();
}
```

The current user that is logged, i am putting that user id to Shared preferences
In my second Table i have something like this

```
task_Id user_id title   content
 1      null    Eat      go to Mc
```

user_id is null here, and i don't know why

i want something like this

```
task_Id user_id title   content
 1      2    Eat      go to Mc
```

user_id- should  be which user id make the todo

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya, because is not working, i was testing that so i commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that you already know how to store and get the userid from the shared preferences.

In your `addTask` activity, add:

```
private String userId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    userId = sharedPreference.getString("USER_ID",null);
    ...
}
```

in the `addItem()` add:

```
private void AddItem() {
    ...
    todo.setUserId(userId);
    ...
}
```

in the DB `add()` use this:

```
public void add(ToDo todoTask) {
    ...
    values.put(USERID, todoTask.getUserId());
    ...
}
```

***OR:***

Another approach is to get the value directly from the DB class if you are sure that you will never insert task for other users.

```
public void add(ToDo todoTask) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    String d = sp.toString();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TITLE, todoTask.getTitle());
    values.put(CONTENT, todoTask.getContent());
    values.put(user_Id,todoTask.getUserID(d));

    db.insert(mTODO, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

and in the constructor save the context for further use.

```
private Context ctx;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.ctx = context;
}
```

Comment: Do i need declare SharedPrerences  in my add method and db?

Comment: No you don't! My first answer is all you need, the second part it is just because I noticed some commented lines in your code, but keep the logic outside the db controller it is a best practice in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating ToDo Table using user_id. while static String refrenced is userid: hence in database when entered it goes null by default

```
   //Table mToDo task name
private final static String mTODO = "Todos"; 

//Todos table columns names
private final static String TASK_ID = "task_Id"; 
private final static String user_Id =  "userId"; //<----Wrong Here
private final static String TITLE = "title";
private final static String CONTENT = "content";

private String CREATE_mTODO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + mTODO + "("
    + TASK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + user_Id + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
    + TITLE + " TEXT," + CONTENT + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Also here is something more for you, Simply you must supply the User Id value to the Field. Below are Some Examples How to do So

```
 private static final String TAG = "DB_HANDLER";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 15;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ElmexContactsManager.db";

/*-------------------------------------------BIZ_SEGMENT----------------------------------------*/
private static final String TABLE_BIZ_SEGMENT = "BizSegment";

/*01*/private static final String KEY_LOCAL_BIZ_SEGMENT_ID = "LocalBizSegmentId";
/*02*/private static final String KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT_ID = "BizSegmentId";
/*03*/private static final String KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT = "BizSegment";
/*04*/private static final String KEY_ADDED_ON = "AddedOn";
/*05*/private static final String KEY_UPDATED_ON = "UpdatedOn";

  /*-------------------------------------------BIZ_SEGMENT----------------------------------------*/
    String CREATE_TABLE_BIZ_SEGMENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BIZ_SEGMENT + "("
  /*01*/ + KEY_LOCAL_BIZ_SEGMENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
  /*02*/ + KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT_ID + " INTEGER,"
  /*03*/ + KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT + " TEXT,"
  /*04*/ + KEY_ADDED_ON + " TEXT,"
  /*05*/ + KEY_UPDATED_ON + " TEXT"
            + ")";

public ContactDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {  try {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BIZ_SEGMENT);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT_TYPE);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT_SOURCE);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONT_INDUSTRY);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MARKETING_REGION);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MARKETING_REGION_BLOCK);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT_MASTER);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT_DET);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Table Craeted ");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_BIZ_SEGMENT);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT_TYPE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT_SOURCE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONT_INDUSTRY);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MARKETING_REGION);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MARKETING_REGION_BLOCK);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT_MASTER);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT_DET);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    Log.d(TAG, "Table Udgraded to Version :" + i1);
}

/*-------------------------------------------BIZ_SEGMENT----------------------------------------*/
public void addBizSegment(BizSegment bizSegment) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT_ID, bizSegment.getBizSegmentId());
    values.put(KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT, bizSegment.getBizSegment());
    values.put(KEY_ADDED_ON, df.format(bizSegment.getAddedOn()));
    values.put(KEY_UPDATED_ON, df.format(bizSegment.getUpdatedOn()));
    // Inserting Row
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_BIZ_SEGMENT, null, values);
    //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
    sqLiteDatabase.close(); // Closing database connection
}

public void updateBizSegment(BizSegment bizSegment) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT_ID, bizSegment.getBizSegmentId());
    values.put(KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT, bizSegment.getBizSegment());
    values.put(KEY_ADDED_ON, df.format(bizSegment.getAddedOn()));
    values.put(KEY_UPDATED_ON, df.format(bizSegment.getUpdatedOn()));
    // Inserting Row
    sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_BIZ_SEGMENT, values, KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(bizSegment.getBizSegmentId())});
    //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
    sqLiteDatabase.close(); // Closing database connection
}

public List<BizSegment> getBizSegmentAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    List<BizSegment> bizSegmentList = new ArrayList<BizSegment>();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BIZ_SEGMENT;

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            try {
                BizSegment bizSegment = new BizSegment(cursor.getInt(0),
                        cursor.getInt(1),
                        cursor.getString(2),
                        df.parse(cursor.getString(3)),
                        df.parse(cursor.getString(4)));
                bizSegmentList.add(bizSegment);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
    return bizSegmentList;
}

public void deleteBizSegment(BizSegment bizSegment) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_BIZ_SEGMENT, KEY_BIZ_SEGMENT_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(bizSegment.getBizSegmentId())});
    db.close();
}
```

Other method is Using Shared Preference suitable for limited Data. It does not provide any relationships. I use this to store basic User related Data. Not for complicated/Relational Large Data. For That Sqlite is preferred.

```
public class AppPreference {

SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

/**
 * @param clientMaster object to set preference
 * @param context      Context of call
 */
public void putPreference(ClientMaster clientMaster, Context context) {

    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("AppPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = pref.edit();

    edit.putInt("ClientId", clientMaster.getClientId());
    edit.putString("FirstName", clientMaster.getFirstName());
    edit.putString("LastName", clientMaster.getLastName());
    edit.putString("Mobile", clientMaster.getMobile());
    edit.putInt("PincodeId", clientMaster.getPincodeId());
    edit.putString("Email", clientMaster.getEmail());
    edit.putString("Password", clientMaster.getPassword());
    edit.putString("MembershipCode", clientMaster.getMembershipCode());
    edit.putString("MembershipIssueDate", clientMaster.getMembershipIssueDate().toString());
    edit.putString("MembershipExpiryDate", clientMaster.getMembershipExpiryDate().toString());
    edit.putString("MemberShipUpdatedOn", clientMaster.getMemberShipUpdatedOn().toString());
    edit.putString("MemberShipQRCode", clientMaster.getMemberShipQRCode());
    edit.putInt("ReferredByTypeID", clientMaster.getReferredByTypeID());
    edit.putInt("ReferredByID", clientMaster.getReferredByID());
    //edit.putString("LastPasswordUpdatedOn", clientMaster.getLastPasswordUpdatedOn().toString());
    edit.putString("TempMembershipCode", clientMaster.getTempMembershipCode());
    edit.putString("AddedOn", clientMaster.getAddedOn().toString());
    //edit.putString("UpdatedOn", clientMaster.getUpdatedOn().toString());
    edit.putBoolean("Login", true);
    edit.putBoolean("Skip", false);
    edit.commit();
}

/**
 *
 * @param appLanguage
 * @param context
 */
public void putLanguagePreference(String appLanguage, Context context) {

    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("AppPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("AppLanguage", appLanguage);
    edit.commit();
}

/**
 * To clear All Object preference & Login False
 *
 * @param context Context call
 */
public void clearPreference(Context context) {
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("AppPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = pref.edit();

    edit.clear();

    edit.putBoolean("Login", false);
    edit.commit();

}

/**
 * @param InstanceId Instance Id
 * @param context
 */
public void putPreferenceInstance(String InstanceId, Context context) {

    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("AppPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("InstanceId", InstanceId);
    edit.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: What are you suggest me to change,  i am not sure really..Sorry i am beginner

Comment: You  must understand the usage and difference for Shared Preference and Sqlite. Your reason for ) in user id is for using Wrong string value.

Comment: For storing Basic Values Shared Preference is good. But while Using more detailed SQL Relational Database(Sqlite which you were using) is appropriate when there is much large data. My Code is related to SQLite

Comment: Ill give u More Sample regarding using Shared preference.

Comment: Have addded an example of Shared preferences from one of my app. check that

Comment: Could you tell me what to change really, i don't have that experience to know about sharedpreference and sqlite.

Comment: In Your Posted Code, you only need to chance ::::: private final static String user_Id =  "userId";  to   private final static String user_Id =  "user_Id";

Comment: Change the field/Column static string "userid" value to "use_id"  for todo table strings.